# How to find 10 business days prior to today's date c#

Tags: c#

I have a scenario where I have to find 10 business days prior to today's date. That is if today is 19-March-2015. 
My out put should be 5-March-2015.

How do I do this using C#

Comment: Is it your homework? What have you tried?

Comment: You will need business logic to determine what constitutes a business day. Is it Monday-Friday? What about holidays? Do all countries celebrate the same holidays?

Comment: Please perform proper research and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string Calculate(DateTime today)
{
    DateTime currentDate = today;    
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        if ((int)currentDate.DayOfWeek >= 6 || (int)currentDate.DayOfWeek == 0)
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-2);
            currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-1);
        }
        return currentDate.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for countries where the weekend's at Saturday and Sunday, and it also won't work for public holidays (which may or may not be fine, depending on requirements).

Comment: Your answer won't build. Also, why cast `DateTime.DayOfWeek` to an `int` when you could use, say, `DayOfWeek.Saturday`, etc.?

Comment: The code give basic idea to full fill the requirement, according to the business logic change it as you like

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                if (currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                    currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-2);

                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(-1);
            }